# How do I call the AWS SDK's Athena API with async/await?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-athena

The AWS SDK's Athena API has a function with this signature:

```
startQueryExecution(params: Athena.Types.StartQueryExecutionInput, callback?: (err: AWSError, data: Athena.Types.StartQueryExecutionOutput) => void): Request<Athena.Types.StartQueryExecutionOutput, AWSError>;
```

This uses a callback (2nd param), so I have to call it like this:

```
athenaAPI.startQueryExecution(params, (err, data) => {...});
```

I'd prefer to call it like this:

```
const result = await startQueryExecution(params);
```

How can I convert this function (maybe using node's promisify, but I don't care how) to work with promises instead of callbacks?

I know I'm typing mostly untyped javascript, but I'd prefer an answer that uses types with typescript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AWS SDK for JavaScript you can add `.promise()` to any API call to get a promise:

```
const response = await athenaAPI.startQueryExecution(params).promise()
```

You can read more about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html

Comment: Wow thank you.  I didn't realize it would be that easy.  What type is that response going to be in this case?

Comment: `response` is a promise, it's value is the same as the `data` parameter in the callback version. It's all in the docs that I linked to.

Comment: Make sure to wrap this in an async function. (in case you don't know already)